# Ionic 2/Angular 2 promise returning observable

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, observable, ionic2, es6-promise

I have a situation where I need to fetch a piece of data from storage in an Ionic 2 application and then use that data to create an HTTP request. The problem that I am running into is that the SqlStorage methods return promises and the http meth returns an observables. I'm having to do something like this to get it to work:

```
 getToken() {
    return this.storage.get('token').then((token) => {
        this.token = token;
        return token;
    });
 }

 loadStuff(){
    return this.tokenService.getToken().then(token => {
      return this.http.get("https://www.urltodatasource.com/api/v1/Endpoint?access_token="+token).map(res => res.json());
    });
  }
```

and then doing something like this to get it to work:

```
this.tokenService.loadStuff().then(observable => {
    observable.subscribe(data => {
         this.storage.set('stuff', data);
         return data;
    });
})
```

I'm very new to Angular and Ionic in general, so I feel like there is a much better way to accomplish what I'm trying to do, but I just don't know how. Also, all of the available resources out there about observables get **very** complicated **very** quickly which leaves an impressionable young developer like me very confused.

Can anyone shed some light on how to do this any better? Thanks!

Comment: In `loadStuff`, is `this.http` the Angular2 `Http` service?

Comment: Yup @yarons it is. Normal Http service being imported at the top of the file and added as a dependency in the constructor of my "StuffService".

Answer (score 11):

Here's what you can do:

Your code below

```
 getToken() {
    return this.storage.get('token').then((token) => {
        this.token = token;
        return token;
    });
 }
```

changes to

```
getToken: Observable<any> = 
    Observable.fromPromise(this.storage.get('token').then(token => {
    //maybe some processing logic like JSON.parse(token)
    return token;
}));
```

Then in your component you can consume it like would any other observable.

```
this.serviceClass.getToken.subscribe(token => { 
//whatever you want to with the token
});
```

Comment: Don't foget: import {Observable} from "rxjs";

Answer (score 3):

In angular 2, the `Http` service functions (`get`, `post`, etc.) return an [`Observable` object](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html#!#rxjs). This is just the way they implemented it.

If you're used to promises, and want your service to return a promise instead, you can use the `toPromise` function that's built in `Observable` objects.

```
loadStuff(){
    return this.tokenService.getToken().then(token => {
        return this.http.get("https://www.urltodatasource.com/api/v1/Endpoint?access_token="+token).toPromise());
    });
}
```

And then

```
this.tokenService.loadStuff().then(data => {
    data = data.json(); //you might need to do that, depending on the structure of the response
    this.storage.set('stuff', data);
    return data;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work using a combination of `Observable.fromPromise()` and `.flatMap()`:

```
getToken() {
    return Observable.fromPromise(this.storage.get('token')
    .then((token) => {
        return token;
    }));
}

loadStuff(){
    return this.tokenService.getToken()
    .flatMap(token => {
        return this.http.get("https://www.urltodatasource.com/api/v1/Endpoint?access_token="+token)
        .map(res => {
            return res.json();
        });
    });
}

this.tokenService.loadStuff().subscribe(data => {
    this.storage.set('stuff', data);
    return data;
});
```

You'll also need to add these imports:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/fromPromise';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **' Observable.fromPromise '** to convert promise to observable.