# Ionic/Angular - retrieve token from storage and append to url

Tags: asynchronous, get, angular5, angular-http-interceptors, ionic-storage

I store authToken in `ionic storage`, whose `get` method is async. When I make `http` request, I need to get this token from storage and append to request as url param. What I tried is :

```js
getUsers(): Observable<any> {
    this.storage.get('authToken').then((token) => {
      return this.http.get(`${API_URL}/users?token=${token}`);
    });
  }
```

In Angular, http service returns `Observable`, that's why I put `getUsers(): Observable<any>` but it raises error `a function whose declared type is neither void nor any must return a value`...

How to deal ionic's asynchronous `get` method generally? Http interceptor came on my mind, to get this token from storage and append it to every request except where route is `/login` and `/register`, but I don't know how to implement it.

Comment: I think this question might be duplicated and maybe solved here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37994343/ionic-2-angular-2-promise-returning-observable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ionic 2/Angular 2 promise returning observable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37994343/ionic-2-angular-2-promise-returning-observable)